# Accessing the elements using [ ] operator on a pointer to wstring

Tags: c++, pointers, wstring

I am unable to use to [] operator on a pointer to a `wstring` object before converting it to const reference using `c_str()` function.

In my program `getwString()` returns a pointer to `wstring`

This is working:

```
`if(obj->getwString()->c_str()[5]!='H')`
```

This is not:

```
`if(obj->getwString()->[5]!='H')`
```

How can I dereference it instead of using `c_str()` function Need Help

Comment: You should be comparing it to a wide character and probably shouldn't be returning a pointer from that function in the first place.

Comment: `if( obj->getwString()->operator[](5) != L'H' )`

Answer (score 1):

There is another dereference operator besides `->` for cases like this one, the `*` operator:

```
std::wstring * ptr = obj->getwString();
(*ptr)[5];
```

or simply

```
(*obj->getwString())[5];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was placing the asterisk somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to access it that way you can do it like this:

`if(obj->getwString()-> operator [](5) != 'H')` , but this is not very pretty.